# Testing a code from a private blockchain and deploy a smart contract

Tags: node.js

I'm testing code from a private blockchain and deploy a smart contract but when I run the command as an administrator "npm install locus --save" the following errors are displayed

C:\Users\Dell\myApp\peerbet-for-book\peerbet-for-book>npm install locus --save
npm WARN deprecated parse-stack@0.1.4: Use error-stack-parser instead.

> deasync@0.1.15 install C:\Users\Dell\myApp\peerbet-for-book\peerbet-for-book\node_modules\deasync
>   node ./build.js

`win32-x64-node-12` exists; testing
Binary is fine; exiting

> locus@2.0.1 postinstall C:\Users\Dell\myApp\peerbet-for-book\peerbet-for-book\node_modules\locus
>   mkdir ./histories

La syntaxe de la commande n’est pas correcte.
npm WARN sportsbet@1.0.0 No description

npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! locus@2.0.1 postinstall: `mkdir ./histories`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the locus@2.0.1 postinstall script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\Dell\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache_logs\2019-06-09T14_37_26_080Z-debug.log

Answer (score 0):

The package is not maintained. Install previous working package `npm install -D locus@2.0.0` or the fixed fork `npm install -D @huangchaowh/locus`

Always remember to check the corresponding git repo [issues](https://github.com/buildize/locus/issues) tab and last update date for the package to get an idea of the current maintenance status and the possible bugs.